# Perl split suddenly stops

Tags: perl, split

I have a csv file (toharvest_og_sourcing_acts.csv), with the following rows:

```
No. 2,Sep/1900/28
No. 3,Sep/1900/28
No. 4,Sep/1900/28
... (Deleted lines, but my line is up until line 403)
No. 2,Sep/1900/28
No. 3,Sep/1900/28
No. 4,Sep/1900/28
```

I have the following Perl script to iterate through this csv line by line:

```
my $file = 'toharvest_og_sourcing_acts.csv';
my $url = 'https://elibrary.judiciary.gov.ph/thebookshelf/docmonth/';

my @list;
open (my $csv, '<', $file) || die "cant open";

foreach (<$csv>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split(/\,/);       
   my $urlcomplete = "$url"."$fields[1]";       
   print "$urlcomplete";
}
```

What I wanted to do is print all first element [1] (start counting from zero) of every rows of the csv prepended by the URL ($url). However, when I run the perl script, it stops and won't print me the desired result in the commandline. What I'm getting instead is it seems the script runs for like a millisecond and below is what is outputted:

`hebookshelf/docmonth/Mar/1923/28`

With a small set (e.g. less than five), I can see the URLs (e.g. https://elibrary.judiciary.gov.ph/thebookshelf/docmonth/May/1902/28) are outputted. How come with 403 rows, the behavior is different?

Comment: Do you want the first element? That would be $field[0], not $field[1]. I added a newline at the end of the print so it would be printed one each line. And it worked with me as it should. What's your environment? I'm running strawberry perl 5.30.

Comment: Hi! It seems I need to add the newline at the end is what I'm missing. I thought it's going to print it continuously in one line. By the way, my environment 5.24.1 and $field[0] is my zeroeth element and $field[1] is my first element, hence, I added [1] in my explanation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify if the following code produces expected result

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname    = 'toharvest_og_sourcing_acts.csv';
my $url_base = 'https://elibrary.judiciary.gov.ph/thebookshelf/docmonth/';
my $regex    = qr(^No. \d+,\w{3}/\d{4}/\d{2});

open my $csv, '<', $fname
    or die "Can't open $fname";

while (<$csv>) {
   chomp;
   next unless $regex;
   my $url = $url_base . (split '\,')[1];       
   say $url;
}

close $csv;
```

Comment: Hi! This script works perfectly well. Never knew of the feature 'say', will have to read up on it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @schnydszch - [perl say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say), [A Beginner's Introduction to Perl 5.10](https://www.perl.com/pub/2008/04/23/a-beginners-introduction-to-perl-510.html/).

Comment: You can use a different delimiter than `/` for `qr()` to avoid having to escape the slashes.

Comment: No sense in over-optimising and using `[a-z]` in a single character class and then using the `/i` modifier to compensate for that. Just use `\w`. I fixed it for you, including my other comment.

Comment: @TLP - `\w{3}` is too broad for month abbreviation - `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlre). `\w{3}` would allow something as **_a8** in place of month.

Comment: What about `[A-Za-z]` then?

Comment: @TLP -- then why not `/[a-z]/i`?

Comment: The `/i` modifier affects the whole regex. Use the minimum requirement to make the regex match.

Comment: @TLP -- how `/i` affects `\d`? I could make very strict regex -- it is just a simplified demo code to achieve desired result (without taking in account all possibilities and making exact regex to exclude none matching information).